# DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401] Dart Flutter

Tags: nodejs, express, flutter, dart

Hola soy nuevo en dart y estoy buscando una manera para que dart pueda interpretar el error 401 como datos de Login erroneos, cuando los datos son correctos, todo perfecto ya que desde el backend (Nodejs express) compruebo los datos y si esta todo correcto envio un estado 200 al pasar esto se redireccionna al dashboard, pero si los datos son erroneos la aplicación crashea mostrando los errores publicados al final.

La idea sería que muestre un cuadro componente en el Login del celular que diga "Los datos son erroneos"

```
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from "express";
import User from "../models/user.model";
import { LoginUserType } from "../schemas/user.schema";



export const getUser = async (
  req: Request<unknown, unknown, LoginUserType>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });
    if (!(await user.comparePasswords(user.password, req.body.password))) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });
    }

  

    res.json(user);
    console.log(user);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

---

```
//=================================DART=======================================
  Future submit() async {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "http://x.x.x.x:3000",
      connectTimeout: 3000,
      receiveTimeout: 3000,
    );
    Dio dio = Dio(options);
    dio.options.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/json;charSet=UTF-8';
    try {
      var response = await dio.post("/api/signin",
          data: {'username': user.userName, 'password': user.password});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(response.data);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const startLogin()),
        );
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
      throw ('Error en el POST');
    }
  }
```

---

Errores:

```
I/flutter ( 7805): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
I/flutter ( 7805): Source stack:
I/flutter ( 7805): #0      DioMixin.fetch
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488
I/flutter ( 7805): #1      DioMixin.request
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483
I/flutter ( 7805): #2      DioMixin.post
package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:97
I/flutter ( 7805): #3      _SinginState.submit
package:transgasan_app/components/singin.dart:30
I/flutter ( 7805): #4      _SinginState._buttonLogin.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:transgasan_app/components/singin.dart:171
I/flutter ( 7805): #5      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:989
I/flutter ( 7805): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:198
I/flutter ( 7805): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:608
I/flutter ( 7805): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:296
I/flutter ( 7805): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:267
I/flutter ( 7805): #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:157
I/flutter ( 7805): #11     Gesture
```

Comment: probaste desde postman primero?

Comment: Si y todo bien si lanzo usuario o password erronea desde postman, me da el response de credenciales incorrectas mas el error 401 que le estoy mandando. 

Mi pregunta es como controlar ese status code 401 en dart flutter, para que no crashe la app y poder mostrar que paso un error por parte del cliente(datos erroneos)

Comment: si entra a tu condición?  else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print(response.statusCode);
      }

Comment: No logra pasar a else if (response.statusCode == 401), recibe el status code 401 y directamente pasa al catch (e){throw ('Error en el POST');}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que `Dio` lanza su propia excepción cuando el request/post no es exitoso.

Leyendo la documentación: https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors

Necesitas capturar la excepción de Dio y validar ahí el status code:

```dart
try {
  //...
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
  if (e.response != null) {
    print(e.response.data)
    print(e.response.headers)
    print(e.response.requestOptions)
    if (e.response.statusCode == 401) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
  } else {
    // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
    print(e.requestOptions)
    print(e.message)
  }
}
```